# bash sed substitution in httpd.conf

Tags: bash, text, sed, substitution

I am trying to replace a line of text in a file using sed and bash. Here is my code. I think my syntaxs may just be off.

> sed -e 's/DocumentRoot /var/www/html/s///usr/share/rt3/html/' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using sed and file paths, it's easier to avoid the "/" delimiter, else you'll be escaping it everytime. This "picket fence" format makes it terrible to read.

Assuming you're trying to replace "DocumentRoot /var/www/html" with "DocumentRoot /usr/share/rt3/html/", try this:

```
sed 's_DocumentRoot /var/www/html_DocumentRoot /usr/share/rt3/html/_' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Example:

```
~> echo "DocumentRoot /var/www/html" | sed 's_DocumentRoot /var/www/html_DocumentRoot /usr/share/rt3/html/_'
DocumentRoot /usr/share/rt3/html/
~>
```

EDIT: From your comment, you're wanting to 1) open the file, 2) replace the string, and 3) save changes to the original file. In this case, you can use sed's `-i` flag (in-place editing). Try this:

```
sed -i 's_DocumentRoot /var/www/html_DocumentRoot /usr/share/rt3/html/_' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Example:

```
~> echo "DocumentRoot /var/www/html" > file
~> cat file
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
~> sed -i 's_DocumentRoot /var/www/html_DocumentRoot /usr/share/rt3/html/_' file
~> cat file
DocumentRoot /usr/share/rt3/html/
```

Comment: that did not work but you did understand what i am trying to do.

Comment: this is what i am trying to script. #Open /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf Change DocumentRoot "/var/www/html" To DocumentRoot "/usr/share/rt3/html"#

Comment: To open the file, make the change, and re-write to the same file, it's best to use sed's `-i` flag (in-place editing). Try this:


`sed -i 's_DocumentRoot /var/www/html_DocumentRoot /usr/share/rt3/html/_' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment: still no change in the file using sed -i 's_DocumentRoot /var/www/html_DocumentRoot /usr/share/rt3/html/_' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: Are you sure the target string exists in the file? Specifically, `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` (spacing included). I added an example to the original post so show how to use it.

Comment: sorry it was DocumentRoot "/var/www/html" can I escape those using \ . I appreciate this help very very much.